# BufferedReader / Scanner Last Line Reading Issue

Tags: java

While solving  a problem at hacker-rank I am facing the issue that scanner/bufferedreader is unable to read the last. As the input provided by them is like

```
10

abcdefghijk

2

R 1 2

W 3 4
```

So both scanner/bufferedreader is unable to read the last line. If the input is like then the code seems to work fine.

```
10

abcdefghijk

2

R 1 2

W 3 4
```

(End of Input)

```
public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        String inputString = input.nextLine();
        int qc = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(len + inputString + qc);
        for(int i=0;i<qc;i++){
            String l = input.next();
            int le = input.nextInt();
            int ri =  input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(l+le+ri);
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the sample code which I am using. I know that we need a \r or\n at the end of line to readline from scanner / bufferedreader. But can anyone provide a solution to this issue as input comes from system that is predefined.

Comment: Your last iteration of the loop ends with `input.nextLine()`, and thus blocks until it finds an EOL, or until the input stream is closed, but there is no EOL, and System.in is never closed.

Comment: I have tried without input.nextLine() also but its giving the same result.

Answer (score 3):

`BufferedReader` would read the last line even if it does not end in a line break. `System.in` is the culprit, that does its own line buffering.
A native system thing: suppose you pressed a couple of backspaces to change the last number...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
input.nextLine();
String inputString = input.nextLine();
```

You are consuming a line to just throw it away.

The other thing is: especially when dealing with standard libraries - don't *assume* that something is broken/doesn't work. In 99,999% of all case the problem is something within **your** code.

Comment: That line of code is used to read the rest of the line of input (newline character after the int token). Thanks for your input.